# Loop through Areas/Regions in worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet with a bunch of different areas that I'd like to loop through.  I'm going to be doing some calculations, and thought it'd be quicker/more efficient than going cell by cell in a column.

I've tried a few different things, but can't figure out how to jump down to the next area.  I've made some comments, the most promising is the last one (`For each cel in rng...`, but after I do the first `cel.CurrentRegion.Select`, and then do things, how do I jump to the next region?

[Here's a zany .gif of what that does as-is...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34h4X.gif)

```
Sub loop_through_zones()
Dim rng As Range, area As Range, singleArea As Range, cel As Range
Set rng = Range("A2:D15")

For Each area In rng.Areas ' This just selects all the data.
    area.Select
Next area

For Each area In rng.CurrentRegion ' this just loops through cells in an area.
    area.Select
Next area

For Each cel In rng
    cel.CurrentRegion.Select ' gets current region!
    'do something with region here
   ' ...
    ' now, go to the next REGION, not cel in current area...?
Next cel

End Sub
```

[image]

So I'd like to get `A2:D4`, do things, then move on to the next region, `A6:D9`, then move on to `A11:D15`, etc.

Edit: It looks like I can do this with some `For i` looping, but I'm curious if you can do it with the built-in `CurrentRegion`/`Areas`, or if I have to do it kludgy:

```
For i = 2 To lastRow
    Set CurrentRegion = .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(.Cells(i, 9).End(xlDown).row, 4))
    CurrentRegion.Select 
    ' Do things with the current region here...
    i = CurrentRegion.Rows(CurrentRegion.Rows.Count).row + 1
Next i
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try something like this...

```
Sub LoopThroughZones()
Dim lr As Long, iRow As Object
Dim Area As Range, Rng As Range, Cell As Range

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Loopting through each block
For Each Area In Range("A2:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2).Areas
    Area.Resize(, 4).Select
Next Area

'Looping through each cell in each block
For Each Area In Range("A2:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2).Areas
    Set Rng = Area.Resize(, 4)
    For Each Cell In Rng
        Cell.Select
    Next Cell
Next Area
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh man, this is great! It uses the built-in `Areas` which is what I was trying to use/learn, and is pretty intuitive without adding many additional steps.  Thanks! :D

Comment: @BruceWayne You're welcome! Glad you found it helpful. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're adding regions to your spreadsheet, an idea might be to name the first cell of each region with a name like `region-N` (`region-1`, `region-2` etc.).

Then, write your code like this:

```
For j = 1 To n 'where n is the number of regions
    Set currentRegion = Range("region-" & j).CurrentRegion
    For Each cell In currentRegion
        'do your things
    Next cell
Next j
```

Like that, you can add a region each time and as soon as you name a cell with `region-N`, it will be taken by your code.

Of course, you might imagine many ways to make the `n` of the `For Loop` dynamic (if you hardcode it, you will have to change it each time you add a new region). For example:

```
For Each namedRange In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If Left(namedRange,7) = "region-" Then
        Set currentRegion = Range(namedRange).CurrentRegion
        For Each cell In currentRegion
            'do your things
        Next cell
    End If
Next namedRange
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I like it and will probably work that in to some other files I have.  For now, it would add a bit more code to my current macro, but thanks very much for the clever suggestion!

Comment: You're welcome @brucewayne, the answer you chose is indeed the one that fits most your case

Answer (score 0):

I would define each distinct region in an array and then loop through the array to make your amendments / calculations. Something like this:

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub Regions()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim Region() As Range
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, LastColumn As Integer

    'Your worksheet name

    Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Find last row and column of data

    LastRow = wks.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    LastColumn = wks.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

    'Put distinct range areas into an array

    j = 1

    For i = 2 To LastRow

        If Not Cells(i, 1) = "" And (Cells(i, 1).Offset(-1, 0).Value = "" _
        Or wks.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-1, 0).Row = 1) Then

           ReDim Preserve Region(1 To j)
           Set rng = wks.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
           Set Region(j) = _
           wks.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(rng.End(xlDown).Row, rng.End(xlToRight).Column))
           j = j + 1

        End If

    Next i

    Dim rngCell As Range

    For i = 1 To UBound(Region)
        Region(i).Select

             'My test
             For Each rngCell In Region(i)
                   rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1 + i
             Next

    Next i

    End Sub
```

It's a pretty crude method of determining where the next region begins, so if your spreadsheet doesn't have a blank cell inbetween each area you may want to tweak it. Alternatively, a random blank cell in column A could cause some havoc.